# How to project number of a scale in a different scale?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, functions, regression

In the picture below both yellow and red lines are Move Averages of different periods.

The blue line is the value of (RedLine - YellowLine).

When I do the subtraction of the two lines I get as result a number that represents the difference between the two lines (delta).

When I put both scales with one on top of the other on the same axis, I get a kind of mapping (projection) of the small number (the delta) on the "default" scale.

But I need a function to get/transform the small number in the number projected in the default scale, for the image below, would be transform -2.29 into 5,168.27.

At the end, I expect plot the same blue line but in terms of the "default" scale.

How could I do that ?

[image]